# Creating show and hide sections with buttons in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three buttons that when clicking show and individual div but this is done in reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class ModeExtended extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();

    this.busButton = this.busButton.bind(this);
    this.trainButton = this.trainButton.bind(this);
    this.tramButton = this.tramButton.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        isHidden: false,
    }
}


busButton(){
    console.log('Bus Button Was Pressed');
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return{
            isHidden: !prevState.isHidden
        };
    });
}

trainButton(){
    console.log('Train Button Was Pressed');
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return{
            isHidden: !prevState.isHidden
        };
    });
}

    tramButton(){
    console.log('Tram Button Was Pressed');
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return{
            isHidden: !prevState.isHidden
        };
    });
}


render() {
    return (
        <div>   
            <h5>Mode Extended</h5>

            <button onClick={this.busButton}>Bus</button>
            <button onClick={this.trainButton}>Train</button>
            <button onClick={this.tramButton}>Tram</button>





            {this.state.isHidden && (
                <div>
                    <h6>You can show Bus Data Now....</h6>
                </div>
            )}

            {this.state.isHidden && (
                <div>
                    <h6>You can show Train Data Now....</h6>
                </div>
            )}

            {this.state.isHidden && (
                <div>
                    <h6>You can show Tram Data Now....</h6>
                </div>
            )}


        </div>
    )
}
}

export default ModeExtended
```

When I click any of the buttons it shows all bus, tram and train data - how do I get them to just show one thing at a time and making sure that the other states are closed. I am really missing something here and need a pointer or two or three…

How can I add an ID to make each button open separate from each other and when one is clicked how can I close the rest of the divs - or open state, I am so lost here. Please help me out.

Cheers as always!

Here is a [REPL](https://repl.it/repls/NiftyConsiderableScience) of my code:

Comment: you should create two new states from the train and the tram !

Comment: Thanks to everyone who left and answer and comment. Where can one learn more about state?

Comment: @user3502952 Make sure to check official docs from https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have 3 different isHidden properties to control your divs. You can do it like this:

```
this.state = {
    isHiddenBus: false,
    isHiddenTrain: false,
    isHiddenTram: false,
    }
```

and then in your render like this:

```
{this.state.isHiddenBus && (
                <div>
                    <h6>You can show Bus Data Now....</h6>
                </div>
            )}

            {this.state.isHiddenTrain && (
                <div>
                    <h6>You can show Train Data Now....</h6>
                </div>
            )}

            {this.state.isHiddenTram && (
                <div>
                    <h6>You can show Tram Data Now....</h6>
                </div>
            )}
```

also your buttons have to change to state accordingly to this.

```
busButton(){
    console.log('Bus Button Was Pressed');
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return{
            isHiddenBus: !prevState.isHiddenBus
            isHiddenTram: false
            isHiddenTrain: false
        };
    });
}

trainButton(){
    console.log('Train Button Was Pressed');
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return{
            isHiddenTrain: !prevState.isHiddenTrain
            isHiddenBus: false
            isHiddenTram: false

        };
    });
}

    tramButton(){
    console.log('Tram Button Was Pressed');
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return{
            isHiddenTram: !prevState.isHiddenTram
            isHiddenTrain: false
            isHiddenBus: false
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey Octobus, this is pretty neat and what I am looking to achieve but I have an issue, so when I click bus and that is open, then I click tram I want bus close automatically. How can I toggle close other states? Thank you for your amazing help!

Comment: I updated my answer. Just set others to false and it will work. Good luck with your project! @user3502952

Answer (score 2):

you can do somthing like this:

```
            import React, { Component } from 'react';

            export class ModeExtended extends Component {

            constructor() {
                super();

                this.state = {
                    curDivIndex:0,//currently visible div index
            //        isHidden: false,
                }
            }


            renderDiv=()=>{
                switch(this.state.curDivIndex){
                    case 1:return  <div>        <h6>You can show Bus Data Now....</h6>    </div>
                    case 2:return  <div>       <h6>You can show Train Data Now....</h6>   </div>
                    case 3:return  <div>       <h6>You can show Tram Data Now....</h6>   </div>
                }
                return null
            }
            setVisibleDiv=(index)=>{
                this.setState({curDivIndex:index})
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <div>   
                        <h5>Mode Extended</h5>
                        <button onClick={()=>{this.setVisibleDiv(1)} }>Bus</button>
                        <button onClick={()=>{this.setVisibleDiv(2)}}>Train</button>
                        <button onClick={()=>{this.setVisibleDiv(3)}}>Tram</button>
                        {this.renderDiv()}
                    </div>
                )
            }
            }

            export default ModeExtended
```

**EDIT**

you want to have three different buttons, on click of each certain div
needs to be visible.
you can achieve this by maintaining the index of currently visible div.
when user clicks any button you have to set the index of div to be visible
which in the above code is achieved by using setVisibleDiv(index) call.
and you can at rendering time use curDivIndex to decide visible div.

Comment: Please explain your code for @user3502952 to understand how you achieve to solve his problem

Comment: @t3__rry  sure i would like to do it!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can achieve this by declaring state properties for all case:

```
this.state = {
  hiddenBus: false,
  hiddenTrain: false,
  hiddenTram: false,
}
```

providing a *name* attribute to your buttons like so:

```
  <button name="hiddenBus" onClick={toggleDisplay}>Bus</button>
  <button name="hiddenTrain" onClick={toggleDisplay}>Train</button>
  <button name="hiddenBus" onClick={toggleDisplay}>Tram</button>
```

then by defining the `toggleDisplay` function to toggle their display:

```
toggleDisplay = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); // default behavior of a clicked button is to send a form so let's prevent this

  const { name } = event.target; // find the clicked button name value 

  this.setState((prevState => ({
    [name]: !prevState[name],
  }));
}
```

Setting`[name]` enables us to target the state prop via the `name`attribute value and update it based on the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Create extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentBtn: null
    };
  }
  clickedButton = e => {
    this.setState({ currentBtn: e.target.id });
  };
  showDivElem = () => {
    const { currentBtn } = this.state;
    switch (currentBtn) {
      case "A":
        return <div>A</div>;
        break;
      case "B":
        return <div>B</div>;
        break;
      case "C":
        return <div>C</div>;
        break;
      default:
        return <div>ABC</div>;
        break;
    }
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.currentBtn);
    return (
      <div>
        <button id="A" onClick={e => this.clickedButton(e)}>
          A
        </button>
        <button id="B" onClick={e => this.clickedButton(e)}>
          B
        </button>
        <button id="C" onClick={e => this.clickedButton(e)}>
          C
        </button>
        {this.showDivElem()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```